# Remove a Number from List of Comma-Separated Numbers

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a list of numbers like following:

```
[123,45,6,78,9]
[45]
[45,123,456]
[1234,45]
[]
[123,4,67,8,9]
```

Suppose I want to remove number `45` to be removed with as little backtracking as possible, I have written following regex:

```
(\[)((?=\])|(45(?=\])|45,|(?>([^,]|,(?!45(?:,|\])))))([^\]\])
```

This regex works for all cases except the last case, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by last case?

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: That regex is invalid - there are some unclosed parentheses and brackets - could you check that?

Comment: Do you have to account for the possibility that there might be `45`s outside of square brackets, and that the regex mustn't match those?

Comment: If you dont care about brackets then the simplest would be: `Regex.Replace(str, "\\b(45,|45|,45)\\b", "");`

Comment: @NiravKamani by last case I mean `[123,4,67,8,9]` - when `45` is not contained in the string

Comment: @TimPietzcker I do apologise, I wrote it right here and didn't paste it from my code. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
(?<=\[)45,?|,?\b45\b
```

In C#:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(?<=\[)45,?|,?\b45\b", "");
```

In [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/10), look at the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- We match `45` in two cases, on either side of the `|` alternation
- On the left, the lookbehind `(?<=\[)` asserts that what precedes is `[`
- `45,?` matches 45 and an optional comma
- OR `|`
- `,?` matches an optional comma
- and `\b45\b` within word boundaries

Comment: What about the empty case `[]` or the case where `45` is not contained?

Comment: @babbupandey: Then the regex does nothing. Why don't you test it? He even provided a test link...

Comment: I accepted it as the answer even though @AvinashRaj's answer is also correct, this is one is succinct :) Thanks for your help, you guys are great!!

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
(?<!\[),45\b|(?<=\[)45,|(?<=\[)45(?=\])
```

Replacement string:

```
empty string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/9)

It removes the number 45 from the comma separated string.

C# code would be,

```
string str = @"[123,45,6,78,9]
[45]
[45,123,456]
[1234,45]
[]
[123,4,67,8,9]";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<!\[),45\b|(?<=\[)45,|(?<=\[)45(?=\])", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Ky4bzH)

Comment: As your demo shows, it fails to remove the `45` from `[45]`.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that @JleruOHeP would have put an answer, but I believe that the regex with the least backtracking is the one he used, with a little tweaking to make it even more backtracking-free:

```
@"\b(?:,45|45,?)\b"
```

With your test cases, the above takes 16, 44, 16 and 46 steps respectively, as seen on the debugger [here](http://regex101.com/r/uP1yL1/1) (you need to click on 'regex debugger' on the left pane to view the number of steps for each match).

The reason for the lower backtracking is that the above doesn't use lookarounds, which add some overheads.